# Change input field type in WordPress Menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, field

In efforts to improve google CPC tracking, i want to add a clickable number to the menu bar. Now the list item i want to change is registered in Appearence -> Menus:

[Menu Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrLtA.jpg)

And this is how it's being displayed on the front end:
[Link to the front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIKmE.jpg)

I want to change the menu to be `<input type="tel" />`, not a list item like now. How it can be done,when the field isn't hard coded ?

Comment: How would this change improve the CPC tracking?

Comment: Long story, is there a way to do ?

Comment: i guess this link may help http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/